# Service to identify incoming fax request in a windows machine.

Tags: c#, windows-services, fax

Is there any possibility to identify incoming fax request from a fax machine or its associated services.

I need to develop an application, which need to identify an incoming fax request along with sender information and stored in a common database. Is it possible to create some kind of service(windows service or windows application) to identify incoming message from a fax machine or any fax associated process or read file from a location where incoming fax message are stored.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

using com component Microsoft Fax Service Extended Com Type library, there's example written in c++, you can translate it to c#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693385(v=vs.85).aspx

and here is a c# example:
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1041737/work-with-fax-using-faxcomexlib